# Java Swing GUI Test Fest JPanel Fixture Error

Tags: java, swing, gui-testing, fest

Trying to use FEST to test my GUI, but I'm having a problem trying to access components that are contained inside a custom JPanel (TopPanel extends JPanel). So the code below is failing when trying to reference the "topPane" which exists as a field inside the MainJFrame. What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class StableAppsUITest {

    private FrameFixture window;
    private JPanelFixture contentFixture;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //Assumes the main class is named "Anagrams" and extends JFrame:
        window = new FrameFixture(new MainJFrame("Title"));
        window.show();
        contentFixture = window.panel("topPanel");

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldEnterAnagramAndReturnTrue() {

        // contentFixture.textBox("mUrlInputTextField").enterText("www.google.com");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        window.cleanUp();
    }

}
```

And here's the stacktrace, in case it's hepful:

> Unable to find component using matcher
>   org.fest.swing.core.NameAndTypeMatcher[name='topPanel',
>   type=javax.swing.JPanel, requireShowing=true].
>
> Component hierarchy: myapp.ui.MainJFrame[name='frame0', title='myapp',
>   enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]   javax.swing.JRootPane[]
>       javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.glassPane']
>       javax.swing.JLayeredPane[]
>         javax.swing.JPanel[name='null.contentPane']
>           myapp.ui.TopPanel[name=null]
>             javax.swing.JLabel[name=null, text='Enter Url: ', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>             javax.swing.JTextField[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>             javax.swing.JButton[name=null, text='Submit', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>           myapp.ui.ContentPanel[name=null]
>             javax.swing.JScrollPane[name=null, enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>               javax.swing.JViewport[,1,1,381x270,layout=javax.swing.ViewportLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=25165832,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isViewSizeSet=true,lastPaintPosition=java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0],scrollUnderway=false]
>                 javax.swing.JList[name=null, selectedValues=[], contents=[], selectionMode=MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, enabled=true,
>   visible=true, showing=true]
>                   javax.swing.CellRendererPane[,0,0,0x0,hidden]
>               javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[name=null, value=0, blockIncrement=10, minimum=0, maximum=270, enabled=true,
>   visible=false, showing=false]
>                 javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=false]
>                 javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=false]
>               javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar[name=null, value=0, blockIncrement=10, minimum=0, maximum=381, enabled=true,
>   visible=false, showing=false]
>                 javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=false]
>                 javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalScrollButton[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=false]
>           myapp.ui.StatusPanel[name=null]
>             javax.swing.JLabel[name=null, text='Status: ', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>             javax.swing.JLabel[name=null, text='', enabled=true, visible=true, showing=true]
>
> org.fest.swing.exception.ComponentLookupException     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.componentNotFound(BasicComponentFinder.java:184)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.find(BasicComponentFinder.java:169)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.find(BasicComponentFinder.java:158)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.core.BasicComponentFinder.findByName(BasicComponentFinder.java:136)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.fixture.ContainerFixture.findByName(ContainerFixture.java:822)
>     at
>   org.fest.swing.fixture.ContainerFixture.panel(ContainerFixture.java:406)
>     at myapp.ui.myappUITest.setUp(myappUITest.java:32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stacktrace, there is a component of type `myapp.ui.TopPanel`, but the name is null (myapp.ui.TopPanel[name=null]).

`window.panel("topPanel")` will search for a JPanel with name "topPanel", so you need to set the name of your component using `mTopPanel.setName("topPanel");`, or use a matcher instead.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Forgot to answer my question. Thanks for that, though. This is what I was missing:
                mTopPanel.setName("topPanel");

Would you please add this line of code to your answer. I think I need to edit my question as well, it was missing some code. It's cool that you firgured it out without it, though. :)